# How to quickly match many high-scoring geocoding ties

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geocoding

I am geocoding Portland Metropolitan Area in ArcMap 10.2 based on Street Address, City, State and Zip. I get decent matches (about 93%). However, I get thousands of high-scoring ties. For example 2 or 3 matches scoring 100%. These tied values are all "separate" points (e.g. two different points within a property polygon, and on point on the street facing the polygon).

Is there a way to either:

1. non-manually match at random based on any one of the top scoring ties, or
2. take the average lat and average long of the top scoring ties?

I am a noob, so I will happily entertain ways to improve this question based on constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Geocoding Options for your locator you should see "Match if best candidates tie", which if you check it, should go ahead a create a match for the top scoring ties.

You could also lower the minimum candidate score, but that is usually more helpful with marginal scores (e.g. 75 not matching if threshold is 80).

For more on geocoding options see the [docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Geocoding_options/002500000048000000/GUID-7A5D855C-CBB9-42AC-BEF7-128044B3B509/).